# Mouseover is messing with the table head, how to fix this?

Tags: html, css, angular

I've got a mouseover and mouseout on my table rows to show links as I hover over. For some reason it when I hover over the rows it shrinks my thead and the links freakout. I cannot figure it out for the life of me. How can I fix this?
Here is the section of my html:

```
<table class="table" id="sessions">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Sessions</th>
                <th scope="col" id="trigger">Next Trigger</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of tableTwo" (mouseover)="showLinks=true" (mouseout)="showLinks=false">
                <td scope="row">{{row.session}}</td>
                <td *ngIf="showLinks" scope="row">
                    <a href="">View</a> 
                    <a href="">Edit</a>
                    <a href="">Trigger Now</a>
                </td>
                <td scope="row" id="trigger">{{row.nextTrigger}} </td>    
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: We would need to also see your CSS.  A lot of things can cause shifts like this, such as changing a font size on `:hover`

Answer (score 2):

You have only 2 header columns in thead, but there are actually 3 columns when rows are generated.
Add one more column in head to balance.

```
<th scope="col">Sessions</th>
<th *ngIf="showLinks"></th>       
<th scope="col" id="trigger">Next Trigger</th>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped with my thead. Now for some reason as I hover over the links it causes the links to flutter. I'm not sure why that would be?

Comment: does this happens even after adding column ? do reload your webpage. it must be working now .

Comment: Yes even after reloading the webpage and adding the column it causes the links to flutter.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot plz .

Comment: Photo added. I couldn't get the picture of the flutter but the View, Edit and Trigger Now links flutter as I hover over them

Comment: picture looks ok to me . You hover on row and all 3 links are visible as per ngIf condition. what is the problem then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201347/discussion-between-jaden-adams-and-bilal-siddiqui).